# iOs goto Facebook post

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there any API that allows me to redirect user to specific facebook post ( i have the post_id ) from iOs App?
I've tried using presentDialogModallyWithSession but there is no normal documentation from facebook as to how this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so until someone comes up with something better this is how you redirect to Safari to a specific post:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=340544892763144&id=100004229085914"]];
```

story_fbid=post id
id=user-id

FBDialog or FBWDialog are not compatible with Facebook Graph API's ( "very smart choice" ).
so you can either use FBDialog / FBWDialog to post / share something ONLY or you can use Graph API to do whatever you want but then you need to build your own UI for showing the results of Graph APIs/